# How to display the similar information in every view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to display the information about user's registration state. It should be displayed on every view, but i consider, that writting this code for about 20 times is a bad idea.  By the way, this is the code, it works, i guarantee that:

View/RegistrationInfo:

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cols="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" height="124"><h2><strong>Simple Blog </strong></h2></td>
    <td width="50%" height="124">

    @if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account"))
        {
        <table width="95%" height="86" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" valign="middle">Hello, @System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name</td>
                        <td width="50%" valign="middle" align = "right"><input type="submit" value="Exit" /></td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
        }
    }
    else
    {
            using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Home"))
            {
                <table width="95%" height="86" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="45%" valign="bottom">Login:</td>
                        <td width="45%" valign="bottom">Password:</td>
                        <td width="10%"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="45%">
                            <p>
                                <input type="text" name="login" />
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="45%">
                            <p>
                                <input type="password" name="password" />
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="left"> 
                            <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="45%" valign="top">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }

        }

     </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr align="left" width="100%" size="2" />
```

As you can see, this view doesn't require to be strongly typed... and i don't know, should I modify any controllers (because, all information is stored in HTML Context), and how. I tried to call

```
@Html.RenderAction("RegistrationInfo", "Home");
```

or
    @Html.RenderPartial("RegistrationInfo", "Home");

and every time i receive compile error with message about invalid parametres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/RegistrationInfo.cshtml")
```

Or if you are inside a view of the Home controller simply:

```
@Html.Partial("RegistrationInfo")
```

Or if you put this partial in `~/Views/Shared/RegistrationInfo.cshtml` you will be able to reference with the shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 2):

While Darin's answer perfectly covers your question, I would point out that registration information seems like it's part of your layout more (master page for the .aspx-inclined) than an actual action.

So what I would do (and indeed, **do** do) is put it either in the header part of your layout in the top right or under your side menu or something, and let the layout handle all the details of rendering it (with a conditional around it to hide it when you're not logged in, so you don't see it on the login screen).

Comment: Actually, I would like to give a possibility to read this simple blog for non-registered users. But user should log-in for posting. So, non-registered users would see textboxes for fast log-in, registered ones would see a greeting. For the AccountConntroller header should be a little bit different: just the left column of the table.... i'm still thinking on it

Comment: That's fine, you can still leave the layout render the logged in "widget", with either the user name+logout button or a "login" mini-form instead. My point still stands, it should most likely be part of the layout instead of including the partial action in every view manually.